# Django - make createview save two different models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

i am trying to get django automatically create instance of 2nd model while creating 1st via CreatView:

```
models.py

class MAG_magazyn(models.Model): #1st
  nr_ident=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  nazwa=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  typ=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  podzespol=models.BooleanField(default=False)
  kategoria=models.ForeignKey(MAG_kategorie_czesci)

class MAG_magazyn_stan(models.Model): #2nd
  id_czesc=models.OneToOneField(MAG_magazyn)
  regal=models.CharField(max_length=3)
  polka=models.CharField(max_length=3)
  stan_min=models.IntegerField()
  stan=models.IntegerField()
  alert=models.IntegerField(default=0)
  rel_stan=models.DecimalField(...)
```

Now, as those models are connected i would like to add instance of 2nd with some default values. My idea was to override form_valid, get last id of 1st model and then create and save 2nd instance :

```
  Class NowyMag (CreateView):
'''
Widok pozwalajacy na dodanie nowej czesci magazynowej do listy
'''

model=MAG_magazyn
fields=[
        (...),
        ]
template_name='magazyn/nowy_mag.html'
success_url=reverse_lazy('mag_lista_mag')

  def form_valid(self, form):
     form.save(  )
     nowy_stan=MAG_magazyn_stan(id_czesc=MAG_magazyn.objects.latest('id').id, regal=0,polka=0,stan_min=0,stan=0, alert=1)
     nowy_stan.save()
     return super(NowyMag, self).form_valid(form)
```

but all i got is:

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: Cannot assign "20": "MAG_magazyn_stan.id_czesc" must be a "MAG_magazyn" instance.
```

Am I thinking correctly, but have mistake, or there is some cleaner way to get something like this working ?

---

a little bit of better explanation:
While creating instance of MAG_magazyn, i would like to automatically create MAG_magazyn_stan with id of created MAG_magazyn and some default values( here all equal to 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I am assuming you are using a Form associated to `MAG_magazyn`, in which case, you want to do something like:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # You need to get a new object based on the form
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    ... # in case you want to modify the object before commit
    self.object.save()
    # not you can use it to assign to the second model
    nowy_stan=MAG_magazyn_stan(id_czesc=self.object, ...)
    nowy_stan.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_absolute_url) # or elsewhere
```

Comment: Yep, exactly what my problem was ! Thank you :) So my problem was that i tied to assign only id but should assign self.object and django magically knows what to do, as those models ore related with OneToOneField ?

Comment: You had two problems. the one you mentioned, and the fact that the object you were trying to assign was not created as you were overwriting the form_valid method, where it is needs to be created. So, the first two lines (or you can make it one line with commit=True) are critical